# boost::bind and reference to temp variable

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, object-lifetime, boost-function

Suppose I have method:

```
void foo(const std::string& s);
```

Can I create boost::function:

```
boost::function<void(const std::string&)> f = boost::bind(foo, temp);
```

where temp is char* that is deleted before `f` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Bind cannot know that the char* can be held in a string, or that it is being passed to a string. To circumvent this, use:

```
boost::bind(foo, std::string(temp));
```

So that your temp is copied into the binder as a string.

Answer (score 0):

And this is compiling for you? It should be

```
boost::function<void()> f = boost::bind(foo, std::string(temp));
```